# How to sort table view items?

Tags: iphone

Are there any built-in tools to sorting cells in a tableview by content title etc ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's assumed that whatever data model you are maintaining behind the table view can be sorted, or accessed in the appropriate order for displaying.  You'll want to study [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource).